# using Python Trying to Increment the JSON object values in a Array before copying the object in a array in a new file

Tags: python, json, copy

I have the following JSON which i am importing in python

```
[{
"title": "Reference Addition",
"ref_date": 20200110,
"country": "ASIA",
"ref_internal": "1",
"ref_external": "1"
}]
```

after import i have saved the data in a variable and changing the values of the JSON Objects to whats needed

```
# open the file and load the data
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
data = json.load(f)
```

changing the values of the objects with following

```
# edit the elements of the JSON Object array
for obj in data:
    obj['title'] = ['title'] + 1
    obj['ref_internal'] = ['ref_internal'] + 1
    obj['ref_external'] = ['ref_external'] + 1
```

After changing i am copying the original data with changed values to a new file

```
# create n copies of the array
copied_data = [copy.deepcopy(data) for _ in range(n)]
```

and saving into a new file using this

```
with open('JSON\NEW_DATA.json', 'w') as f:
json.dump(copied_data, f, indent =4)
```

but each time i want save the array i would like the above values to be incremented but i am struggling to get that done

I keep getting this error for all the fields

```
obj['title'] = ['title'] + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

It might be a silly mistake but I am new to Python and JSON any help of guidance on how i can do that will really help me learn.

Comment: You can't increment string

Comment: `obj['title'] = int(obj['title']) + 1`. When you write `['title']`, that creates a list with one str element `'title'`. But also, it looks like the "title" attribute of your JSON object isn't even a number..?

Comment: Typo? You want `obj['title'] = obj['title'] + 1`. Also you need to convert `str` to `int` before incrementing.

Comment: Either the JSON is incorrectly storing the refs as strings, or you aren't supposed to be doing math on them.

Comment: title seems to be a string, do you mean to append a 1 as a string to the title?

Comment: (I suspect the former; dates should not be stored as numbers, either.)

Comment: As @depperm points out, I have no idea why you are trying to increment the *title*.

Comment: @depperm yeah that is Correct. whats required is i would like to get multiple copies of this array with different titles which is a string so for instance title 1 = "Reference -1" , title for the next copied array to "Reference - 2" and so on

Comment: @JoshClark tried what you suggested
obj['title'] = int(obj['title']) + 1 

 but getting this error now 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate of one or multiple of [these 129 search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22TypeError%3A+can+only+concatenate+list%22)

Comment: i have gone through most of them and did not find any solution but apologies for trying to learn something

Comment: You've given the input JSON but exactly what does the *output* JSON need to look like?  The math you show makes no sense so showing us the desired result would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion 
I expect the output JSON file to be like this with certain values updated, the values are string values

[
 {
  "title": "Reference Addition",
  "ref_date": 20200110,
  "country": "ASIA",
  "ref_internal": "ASIA-1",
  "ref_external": "ASIA-1"
 },{
  "title": "Reference Addition",
  "ref_date": 20200110,
  "country": "ASIA",
  "ref_internal": "ASIA-2",
  "ref_external": "ASIA-2"
 },{
  "title": "Reference Addition",
  "ref_date": 20200110,
  "country": "ASIA",
  "ref_internal": "ASIA-3",
  "ref_external": "ASIA-3"
 }
]

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using the copy and copy_num variable
copied_obj["ref_internal"] = f"{obj['ref_internal']} - {copy_num}"